# Ubuntu versions and using apt-get for SNMP mib downloader

Tags: apt, ubuntu-16.04, snmp

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, which I believe slightly pre-dates a fix to some issues with the SNMP MIBs installed by the snmp-mibs-downloader. I'm trying to understand whether I can use apt-get to install the fixed version of the downloader. My expectation was that as the SNMP artefacts are installed independently of Ubuntu, that the Ubuntu version would not prevent me from install the fixed version of the mib downloader.

If I run

> sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader

I get

> snmp-mibs-downloader is already the newest version (1.1)

However I know that a version 1.1+nmu1 exists, it's documented [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/snmp-mibs-downloader) and appears to be available at sites documented [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/artful/all/snmp-mibs-downloader/download). At the latter site it gives the format of a string I can add to my /etc/apt/source.list file.

> deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main multiverse

In fact I've successfully done this before, for another package only available from this site, so I'm pretty sure the config works.

However I don't see how to request this +nmu1 version, apt seems convinced that 1.1 is the latest version.

I realise that I could either download the tar.gz by hand, or go to a machine with Debian installed and get the fixed MIBs from there, but if I can use APT it feels cleaner. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those packages you linked are for `artful` release which is Ubuntu 17.10.
If you check that same package for `xenial`(which is Ubuntu 16.04) you can see that latest package is in fact 1.1 version:

[snmp-mibs-downloader](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/snmp-mibs-downloader)

Since you still have 1.1 version installed after you added that `artful` version of the package, I assume you did something wrong. So let's try it this way:

1. Remove this `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main multiverse` from `/etc/apt/source.list` file (and wherever else you pasted it).
2. Paste this command `echo "deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snmp-mibs.list`
3. `sudo apt update; sudo apt list --upgradable` and check if `snmp-mibs-downloader` package is in that list. If you see it, feel free to `sudo apt upgrade snmp-mibs-downloader -y` if you only whish to update that package.
4. Remove `artful` repository so you don't accidentally upgrade some package that might break `xenial` installation:
   `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/snmp-mibs.list; sudo apt update -y`

I've tested it on my end and it works:

`root@test:~# cat /etc/os-release ; apt list snmp-mibs-downloader
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.5 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
Listing... Done
snmp-mibs-downloader/artful,now 1.1+nmu1 all [installed]`

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks very much, I now have the 1.1+nmu1 version installed. It seemed like the upgrade you suggested "sudo apt upgrade snmp-mibs-downloader" still wanted to update loads of files. Instead I did an apt-get remove and apt-get install and that gave me the new version. In passing, note: this does fix almost all the defective MIB files, the exception being SNMPv2-PDU, which still has one error.

Comment: Welcome, glad I could help, going to edit the answer to only update that specific package.

Comment: artful release not found, bionic now seems to provide the downloader version